# Fatal Error after instaling a new domain

Tags: magento-1.9, database, error

My new domain that I install on the server can not connect to the browser, but the way that I use the same process to install a previous domain.

The results that appear in my browser are:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in
>   /home/localhost/public_html/settings.php on line 12

Please give me solution to solve this problem

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check if mysqli is loaded with :

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

If not, modify your php.ini by adding :

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
```

Repeat until there are no module missing